# Javascript setTimeout and clearTimeout then proceeding with the remaining functions if a button is clicked not working

Tags: javascript

Below is the code that I have written so far. I want to add a timeout feature so if you open the page and don't click one of the three action buttons the picture changes to picture 6 (the last picture)

Currently I have the timeout feature working and stopping if one of the three buttons is clicked but I need the second onclick to work if the button is pressed.

Example would be if I open the page and click feed I want the timer to stop and the function changeImage to occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var counter = 0;
var myVar;
var myRhino = [
  "https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431",

  "https://img04.deviantart.net/0594/i/2010/261/5/6/happy_rhino_by_ammut88-d2z0sto.jpg",

  "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/angry-rhino-daniel-eskridge.jpg",

  "https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1340/1368093048_fa7ef85a5a_z.jpg?zz=1",

  "https://images.fineartamerica.com/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/1/hungry-rhino-james-sarjeant.jpg",

  "http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1nulfB/users/z/za/zatrokz/600/meRoKDQ.jpg",

  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R_zz1GEkEk4/maxresdefault.jpg",
];

myVar = setTimeout("TimeoutImg()",5000);

function changeImage(btn) {
  if (!btn) {
    counter += 1;
    target.src = myRhino[counter % myRhino.length];
  } else {
    var data = btn.getAttribute('data-values');
    var pics = JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"); // Convert string of numbers to an array
    var num = pics.shift(); // remove index 0 from array and store it in num
    pics.push(num); // Add what was previously at index 0 to end of array
    target.src = myRhino[num];
    counter = num;
    btn.setAttribute('data-values', pics.join(','));
  }
}

function TimeoutImg(){
  target.src = myRhino[6];
}

function TimeoutStop(){
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

```html
<HTML>    
  <head>    
    <center>
      <b> This is My Virtual Pet!</b>
    </center>
    <center> 
      <img id="target" src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/14623/images/magazine_hero/WW188829.jpg?1509653431" width="300" height="250" />    
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value=" Scroll Through Emotions" />         </center>    
    <br>
    <center>
      <input type="button" onclick="TimeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="1,1,2,0" value="Feed">
      <input type="button" onclick="TimeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="6,4,5,2" value="Pet">
      <input type="button" onclick="TimeoutStop()" onclick="changeImage(this)" data-values="3,0,4,4,1" value="Play">
    </center>    
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: tip: `html` code goes inside `body` tag, not `head`. `head` is for let's say "setup" of the page

Comment: @CalvinNunes I don't think that would fix my issue would it? When I did that it just made my other function to change pictures not work.

Comment: No, it won't fix, but it is the correct syntax and it is important to follow that to avoid other issues that write code in head may bring to you.